# ValueError: There are 5 color bins including extensions, but ncolors = 4; ncolors must equal or exceed the number of bins

Tags: deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, semantic-segmentation

I am rasterizing my Shapefiles for creating labels for Semantic Segmentation using U-Net using the following code:

```
rstzr = r.Rasterizer(shape_file,
                     raster_file,
                     class_column,
                     classes_interest = classes_of_interest,
                     non_class_name = non_class)

rstzr.collect_class_names()
rstzr.rasterize_layer()
rstzr.remove_labels_under_cloud(pos_qa = 0, new_label = 3)
m_class_names = ['No Data'] + rstzr.get_class_names() + ['Clouds']
rasterized_layer = rstzr.get_labeled_raster()

rstzr.save_labeled_raster_to_gtiff(out_labels)

vis.plot_labels(rasterized_layer, m_class_names, colors = ['white', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue'], title = "Rasterized Ground Truth")
```

When I am using this code in Google Colab [Rasterized Shapefiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhxKV.jpg), it is working properly and the Rasterized Ground Truth is also being plotted as can be seen in the screenshot. But when I am trying the same code in other Jupyter Platform of my university with high computation performance, it is showing error which can be seen in the screenshot

[image: Error showing in the Jupyter Notebook of my University but working fine in Google Colab]

Can anyone suggest what can be the issue for the error

> ValueError: There are 5 color bins including extensions, but ncolors = 4; ncolors must equal or exceed the number of bins

while it is working properly when I use it with Google Colab?

Comment: Different environments are resulting in different binning it would seem. Where you developed the code you only get four bins & where the error comes up you get five. You'd have to run the code with the same versions of the package(s) involved in binning. Alternatively, pickle your data where you get the expected four and then bring the data over to your University's platform and unpickle it. If you add the extra color it should plot; however, it won't look the same I suspect. How different they look may help you track down the issue or tell you how critical it is to track down.

Comment: I think you are quite correct. When I add the extra colour, the Map gets Plotted but the Colour is different form the one mentioned in the Legend. I am attaching my Jupyter file in the following link. I was wondering if you can tell me as to which package(s) are involved in binning? Thanks.

Jupyter Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FL13KVnk93hNv15Ox_MpTqhVyqyvpyqH/view?usp=sharing